# .htaccess showing 404 page for non existing urls but not for existing directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My htaccess shows correct custom 404 page for non existing pages, but for directories without index file like **domain.com/existingdirectory** it shows default non custom internal error page. Cant figure out where is the issue.

```
ErrorDocument 400 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 408 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
</IfModule>

<Files .htaccess>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

Options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                      application/javascript \
                                      application/json \
                                      application/rss+xml \
                                      application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                      application/x-font-ttf \
                                      application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
                                      application/xhtml+xml \
                                      application/xml \
                                      font/opentype \
                                      image/svg+xml \
                                      image/x-icon \
                                      text/css \
                                      text/html \
                                      text/plain \
                                      text/x-component \
                                      text/xml
                                      application/ld+json \
                                      application/manifest+json \
                                      text/vtt \
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/x-component                      "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/truetype                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"

      <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
      </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite 403 message, too.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
```

Not sure why is is insider of `mod_rewrite` block and why do you want to enable rewrite engine there. You do not need the part below for custom error pages

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> # remove this line 
    RewriteEngine On # remove
    RewriteBase / #remove
    ..... # keep the list of ErrorDocument, but remove everything else.
</IfModule>  # and also remove this line
```

As you can see from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument - it is a core's feature, so it does not need any checkups for other modules. The final code instead of this block will look like

```
ErrorDocument 400 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 408 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: I am really sorry, but as far I understood I modified code of question. `RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /` are now nowhere is file. Apparently issue is fixed. But as I am new please tell is it ok to remove `RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /` completely

Comment: @XIMRX yes, and you do not need `IfModule` condition as you are not using `mod_rewrite` there at all and `ErrorDocument` directive is not related to this module.

Comment: Thanks, and can you go through and point out any other error in file to help me and future visitors.

Comment: @XIMRX what other errors? if you want me to check the config file then it is not enough information to see if something is still need there or not.

Comment: I just meant all what is added in file above, is it added correctly? Thanks anyway bus is fixed

Comment: @XIMRX read my updated answer. I wrote 2 or 3 times, that `ErrorDocument` does not have to be written in `IfModule` block.